# How to properly interconnect Apollo Server / mongodb / express?

Tags: mongodb, express, graphql, apollo-server

I am attemping to use express to serve my static images.  I have attempted to integrate express with Apollo Server in the code below.  Unfortunately, when doing so, the mongodb data no longer displays on the front end.  Is there any issue with my code OR are ApolloServer/Mongodb/Express not compatible?

As a sidenote, when I remove all express content and simply return server.listen() etc it works perfectly (so I realize the disconnect is with express implementation)

**index.js**

```
const { ApolloServer, PubSub } = require("apollo-server-express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const { createWriteStream, existsSync, mkdirSync } = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");

const typeDefs = require("./graphql/typeDefs");
const resolvers = require("./graphql/resolvers");
const { MONGODB } = require("./config.js");

const pubsub = new PubSub();

//server instance
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context: ({ req }) => ({ req, pubsub }),
});

const app = express();
app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../images")));
server.applyMiddleware({ app });

mongoose
  .connect(MONGODB, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("MongoDB Connected");
    return app.listen(5000, () => {
      console.log(`  Server ready at http://localhost:5000/`);
    });
  })
```

Comment: It could be several reasons why the data is not showing up on the front. Do you have an error on the request or does it just not hang up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `apollo-server-express` exposes your GraphQL endpoint at `/graphql`, not `/` like `apollo-server` does. You can customize this behavior by providing a `path` option to `applyMiddleware`. However, I wouldn't change the path back to `/` in this case -- instead just modify your client code to send requests to the correct URL.